# Saving a batch file CURL into a variable

Tags: batch-file, curl, pastebin

Im trying to get the text from a pastebin into a variable from a batch file using CURL, I can get the text using "curl pastebin com/raw/paste" but it only reads it out into the console and im trying to save it to a variable like: 
set txt=curl https://pastebin com/raw/paste

Comment: What you are looking for is called _command substitution_. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: This is what I am looking for but I cant get it working for batch and curl.
Batch File: 
`@echo off
set k = %curl https://pastebin.com/raw/paste%
echo %k%
pause
`
Output:
ECHO is off.
k
Press any key to continue . . .